# What is a good option for raising my kitchen sink?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters, kitchen-sink

We just moved in to a new-to-us house (build in 1986), and I feel like the kitchen sink is "too" low. I've just learned that "standard" counter height is 36 inches; I measure 35 1/4" from the floor to the top of the counter/sink. I'd like to replace the sink and faucet, but I don't need to replace all of the cabinets (so no need to raise the rest of the counter height). What is a good option for creating a slightly higher sink?

Comment: Looks like the floor was redone by adding new over the existing. Are you interested in removing and raising the counter tops? This will be your simplest choice... Replacing the sink will not do it for you I believe, unless it is replaced with a really thick edged cast iron sink.

Comment: To be clear, you just want the sink to be higher, but not the surrounding countertop?

Comment: @Jack it's possible they laid the new floor on top, but if they did, they really tried hard to hide it -- none of the adjoining trim, floors, or built ins look mismatched. Raising the counters is a reasonable option; we would just have to add vertical spacer trim all around. We also couldn't find any sinks that did the trick by themselves.

Comment: @Tester101 yes - that would be ideal. My best idea so far is to bring the (to-be-purchased) countertop up at a 90 degree angle at the sink to put the sink at a good height without having to raise the whole counter.

Comment: When you wrote "to be purchased countertop", it sounds as if a 2 1/4" thick countertop will do it....

Comment: Probably so, @Jack. I was hoping someone might have a more elegant solution, since I am design'-challenged. We'll see how expensive they get. Thank you both for your input!

Comment: What material are you considering?

Comment: Front-runner at this point is laminate. Butcher block is too-high-maintenance for us with 3 young kids. Not trying to be cheap, but granite may be a stretch financially.

Comment: Need to consider what that thick of a countertop like that will look like. If your place has a contemporary look to it, that will help. More traditional homes I feel it would be out of proportion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be very non-standard to raise just sink, and probably more expensive unless the stove is involved.

The cabinets are just screwed to the wall. If you take everything apart you can just raise everything 2 inches or whatever you want. The trickiest part is the drain. You will have to remove a section of the old drainpipe and put in a longer section. Also, the water cables (which are flexible) may or may not have to be replaced with longer versions depending what is there.

If there is a gas stove involved, it could get complicated.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I guess "there isn't a good option" is the answer!

Answer (score 1):

how about measuring the height, width and length of the bottom of the sink (and of course the height of a plastic container which is used in the sink to wash dishes), then finding a flat rectangular piece of plastic with that width and length, but the height will be the height of the sink minus the height of the dishwashing container.

just measured for mine. have no idea what it's called or where to find it, but it will be 5 1/2" x 7" and about 1 1/2" high. not much of a difference.

take care.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.